# How can I set day to 1 when parsing incomplete date with dateutil.parser?

Tags: python, python-2.7, date, python-dateutil

When I use `dateutil.parser` to parse an incomplete date that's missing the day, I get the day set to `10` for some reason:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
>>> d1 = parse('2008 Apr 2')
>>> d1
datetime.datetime(2008, 4, 2, 0, 0)
>>> d2 = parse('2014 Apr')
>>> d2
datetime.datetime(2014, 4, 10, 0, 0)
```

Is there a way to changing this so that the day gets automatically set to `1` instead for such incomplete cases?

Comment: Is it picking up today's day?

Comment: @JasonHeine That's a great observation, I didn't think of that. But I can't be running my processing only on the 1st of each month :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can pass `default` keyword argument. If the `default` is specified, parser will replace default's part with parsed date:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from dateutil.parser import parse
>>>
>>> print parse('2014 Apr', default=datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 1))
2014-04-01 00:00:00
```

According to [`dateutil.parser.parse` documentation](http://dateutil.readthedocs.org/en/latest/parser.html#dateutil.parser.parse):

> **`default`** – The default datetime object, if this is a datetime object
>   and not `None`, elements specified in `timestr` replace elements in the
>   default object.

Comment: Is there any way to define just a default value to the day? My expectation would be for this case `parse("2014 Apr") # 2014-01-01 00:00:00`

Comment: @vildhjarta, Sorry, I don't know the way.